# Two problems with my code so far.

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

fight = False

def start_up():
    print("Fight Simulator - Test Stages.")
    userInput = str(input("Enter your name "))
    user_name = userInput
    return user_name

def intro():
    userName = start_up()
    while True:
        userInput = str(input("Welcome to the dojo, {}. To commence the first battle, type 'Start', or 'Begin'".format(userName)))
        if userInput == "Start" or "start" or "Begin" or "begin":
            return userInput
        else:
            print("Enter a valid response")
            break

def fight_commence():
    userInput = intro()

    if userInput == "Start" or "start" or "Begin" or "begin":
        fight = True

        userHp = 100
        opponentHp = 100

        while fight == True:
            userDmg = randint(0,100)
            opponentDmg = randint(0,100)

            opponentHp -= userDmg

            if opponentHp <= 0:
                opponentHp == 0

            print("You did {} damage".format(userDmg))
            sleep(1)
            print("Opponent has {} hp remaining".format(opponentHp))
            sleep(1)

            if opponentHp <= 0:
                print("You killed him!")
                fight = False
    else:
        print("Enter a valid action")

fight_commence()
```

So for some reason the code doesn't print("Enter a valid response") when a response other than "Start" or "start" or "Begin" or "begin" is given. I want it to loop back to userinput stage, but instead it just carries on with the program as if everything is A ok. I can't figure out where I messed up.

Secondly, I want the opponentHp to automatically equal 0 when the health dips below 0. For instance, when opponentHp = -45, opponentHp should equal 0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Might help if you tag the language....

Comment: "Two problems with my code so far" is not a very specific/searchable title. And your problem is a classic: `if userInput == "Start" or "start" or "Begin" or "begin":` isn't doing what you think it is... (Hint: read it as `if (userInput == "Start") or "start" or "Begin" or "begin":`)

Comment: This could be a good question with some editing, but as it stands now, I am downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Well a big problem with the testing of the 'valid input' is the way your testing.

```
if userInput == "Start" or "start" or "Begin" or "begin"
```

This is not a valid python condition. Instead do something like this:

```
if userInput in ["Start", "start", "Begin", "begin"]
```

This comparison happens twice and is no good. For the `opponenthp` being `0`, you currently have this as your statement and result:

```
if opponentHp <= 0:
    opponentHp == 0
```

The condition is perfectly fine, but the `==` in the action is another conditional operator, you need to change it to:

```
if opponentHp <= 0:
    opponentHp = 0
```

**ADDITION**
Also, in addition to the above items, when you use the `break` statement you will end the infinite loop you have set up and end the function without a returned value, you may want to consider changing it to a `continue` or `pass` statement, or simply remove it.

Answer (score -1):

The conditions (if-clause) are wrong. You should repeat 'userInput==' for every `or`.
Or, more concisely this:

```
userInput.lower() in ["start", "begin"]
```